# swift nil coalescing with doubles

Tags: swift

I generally think if I have to put a ! after anything in swift, that's a sign I've screwed up - swift has so many nil coalescing and let test operations and things that mean you can normally code without introducing a potential crash into the program.   But I have a bunch of variables of type Double?, and I just couldn't find a way of cleaning this up:

```swift
        if (target_value != nil) && (start_value != nil) && (rate != nil)
        {
            number_days = Int(ceil((target_value! - start_value!) / rate!))
            target_date = Date.now().plus(days: number_days! )
        }
        else
        {
            number_days = nil
            target_date = nil
        }
```

is there any easy way of doing this witout putting ! on anything?

Comment: Please learn about [optional binding](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID333).

Comment: Why is `if let` not good enough here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to learn about [optional chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html) , you can use either `if let` or `guard let` and both should work just fine. `guard` will provide early exit while `if let` will give you the option to continue the rest of the function (code block) it depends on your situation and logic.

here is a better code you can use with `guard`:

```
guard let targetValue = target_value,
      let startValue = start_value,
      let rate = rate else {
      number_days = nil
      target_date = nil
      return
}
number_days =  Int(ceil((targetValue - startValue) / rate))
guard let numberDays = number_days else {
      target_date = nil
      return
}
target_date = Date.now().plus(days: numberDays)
```

or you can use `if let` as follow:

```
if let targetValue = target_value,
      let startValue = start_value,
      let rate = rate {
      number_days =  Int(ceil((targetValue - startValue) / rate))
      if let numberDays = number_days {
            target_date = Date.now().plus(days: numberDays)
      }
} else {
      number_days = nil
      target_date = nil
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Nil coalescing is inappropriate, *optional bind* the optionals

```
if let target = target_value,
   let start = start_value,
   let rate = rate {
        let numberOfDays = Int(ceil((target - start) / rate))
        number_days = numberOfDays
        target_date = Date.now().plus(days: numberOfDays)
    }
    else
    {
        number_days = nil
        target_date = nil
    }
```

Consider to use less optionals anyway. And this is not JavaScript. The variable names are supposed to be camelCase.

Comment: Watch out for that `now` static method it might be screwing up the date.

Comment: @LeoDabus That's none of my business 

Answer (score 1):

You can check for several optional values in a single if let, then simply rework how you're using `number_days` or:

```swift
if let target_value = target_value, start_value = start_value, rate = rate {
    let numberDays = Int(ceil((target_value - start_value) / rate))
    number_days = numberDays
    target_date = Date.now().plus(days: numberDays)
}
```